# MP4 not supported in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video, mp4

If I paste the following URL directly into the address bar in Firefox, the video plays just fine:

http://distilleryvesper1-13.ak.instagram.com/744b42900fab11e3a34522000ae80008_101.mp4

However, as soon as I wrap it in HTML5 video tags (as in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X34z4/)), Firefox claims that the video isn't supported:

```
<video width="612" height="612" controls>
  <source src="http://distilleryvesper1-13.ak.instagram.com/744b42900fab11e3a34522000ae80008_101.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I'm using Firefox version 24.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MP4 is not supported in Firefox through the video element unless you are on Vista (since version 22), Windows 7 (since version 21) and 8, Linux (since version 24 but disabled by default until version 26) and Android (since version 17) and then only if a third-party decoder is available for it ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video)).

**Update 1 (2014)** [Current plans](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.media/oxY_kp1Rq4s/b5eOfW13KVgJ) is to also support MP4 for Mac from version 35 (released early next year),

**Update 2 (2016)** It's supported through native APIs [since v35](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/35.0/releasenotes/).

Also from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats):

> Firefox supports the format on some platforms, but only when a
>   third-party decoder is available.

That it plays when you supply the link directly indicates that you have a plugin installed which is capable of showing mp4 (ie. QuickTime or something similar). This and the video element are unrelated however.

To get around this you can supply OGG Vorbis and/or WebM formats. You can use a free converter such as [Miro](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) to support these formats which are supported also in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like Firefox 35 will add MP4 support on Mac. Should release around mid-January. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.media/oxY_kp1Rq4s/b5eOfW13KVgJ

Comment: Firefox now supports in 2016, as of https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/35.0/releasenotes/, as stated by @greg.kindel

Answer (score 2):

FYI, Firefox 35 offered up native support on OSX and Windows in early 2015. 
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/35.0/releasenotes/

Answer (score 1):

You are probably on Mac and you have the QuickTime plug-in installed, so the plug-in plays the video if you navigate directly to it, but it doesn't work in the `video` element, because Mac support for MP4/H.264/AAC isn't ready yet.

As of November 2013 / Firefox 26, Firefox supports MP4/H.264/AAC on Vista and newer Windows, Android and Firefox OS.

Your Fiddle also works on Linux when GStreamer support is enabled and encumbered codecs are installed. (GStreamer support is not yet enabled by default in e.g. builds supplied by Canonical for Ubuntu.)

Comment: What about Mac? Will FF 26 play MP4 on Mac?

Comment: I've been asking questions in the #firefox channel on Mibbit and also been overlooking bugzilla.  So far all I see is talk that they will support it on all platforms as time comes.  So far, for Firfox/Mac users have to wait because of the loyalty fee Firefox would have to pay yearly to ship out the H.264 Codec. This is a pretty big issue which either Apple or Firefox will have to solve.

Comment: Looks like Firefox 34 on Mac will support MP4: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.media/oxY_kp1Rq4s/fVi-aPy70koJ

Comment: Looks like MP4 on Mac didn't make it into Firefox 34 but is planned to be in Firefox 35, which should release mid-January https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.media/oxY_kp1Rq4s/b5eOfW13KVgJ

Answer (score 0):

you may be needing this in case you do not have support for MP4 files:

Windows Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N and for Windows 7 KN:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968211

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546

Also make sure that these prefs have the default value:

media.windows-media-foundation.enabled

media.directshow.enabled