# How to play mp4 video from browser on linux os

Tags: linux, html5-video, mp4

I have tried to a play **MP4** video on Windows by passing an url such as:
`file:///D:/FTP/ScanDoc/14052014_114359.mp4` and it played the video for me.

But when I tried to play the video on Linux using this url: `file:///home/administrator/Documents/FTP/ScanDoc/14052014_114614.mp4`, I am unable to play the video.

My Question is: Is it possible to play videos in a browser on Linux? If yes then how to pass path for specific folder to browser?

**i am using both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox web browser.**

Comment: You might want to add what browser you were working with.

Comment: `@reto` i am using both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox web browser.

Comment: What are the version numbers of the browsers? (this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061175/mp4-not-supported-in-firefox/20061425#20061425)

Comment: Did you checked are you able to play videos from youtube and other video streaming site.s It might be that you might be missing some plugins. What happens when you open to play the mp4 file using file:/// do you see any error or anything else ?