# HTML video tag not working

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I am trying to add a video tag to get a video player with my video like this

[image]

The video shows up fine *sometimes* as shown above, but most of the time it shows up weird and not functional as shown below

[image]

No matter if I click play or not, it just does not work.

Here is my code

```
<div class="detailRight">
        <video id="video1" width="515" height="300" preload controls>
            <source src="../files/MyVid1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it works sometimes and sometimes it does not. How do I get past this bug?

---

EDIT1

Above is in Chrome, in Safari it is working fine, in Firefox it is giving me

[image]

Comment: Is this issue happens in all browsers?

Comment: @Kamil It works fine every time in Safari but in Firefox is giving me a "No video with supported format and MIME type found" error is displayed in the video player. Edited above.

Comment: Are you sure you have the necessary codecs installed for the video you're wanting to play?   Or any necessary plugins that might be required?

Comment: @MisutoWolf Thank you for your reply. I am not sure if I have the codecs installed. How do I go about installing them/other plugins?

Comment: I'd just try to figure out how they are encoded.  What OS are you testing this on?

Comment: I'm on Mavericks. So do you think it is the video encoding that is causing the errors?

Comment: Firefox does not support MP4 natively - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061175/mp4-not-supported-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

in order to support all browsers i would recommend using .ogv .webm and .mp4 formats this should solve your problems their are a couple of online sites that will convert your video for free